# RegEx match for groups that show up in different order

Tags: python, regex

I’m trying to come-up with a RegEx Match Pattern (preferably for Python) for the following possible strings combinations. These are JVM generic args strings with –D switches that may appear in any random order.

How do I account for such random-ness in my RegEx?

So far I have this, but it doesn't work for all the scenarios below. Matches only #1

```
\-javaagent:.+\/javaagent.jar\s+-Dappdynamics\.agent\.applicationName=[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+\s+-Dappdynamics\.agent\.tierName=[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+\s+\-Dappdynamics\.agent\.nodeName=[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\$\{\}]+\s+\-Dappdynamics\.agent\.uniqueHostId=[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\$\{\}]+
```

Search contexts:

1.

```
-javaagent:/path/to/folder/with/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=1234_APP-NAME -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=myTIER-NAME -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=${WAS_SERVER_NAME} -Dappdynamics.agent.uniqueHostId=${HOSTNAME}
```

2.

```
-javaagent:/path/to/folder/with/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=myTIER-NAME -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=1234_APP-NAME -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=${WAS_SERVER_NAME} -Dappdynamics.agent.uniqueHostId=${HOSTNAME}
```

3.

```
-javaagent:/path/to/folder/with/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.uniqueHostId=${HOSTNAME} -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=1234_APP-NAME -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=myTIER-NAME -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=${WAS_SERVER_NAME}
```

Comment: If all the elements are there but are out of order, use an out-of order regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An out of order regex (random placement) of *unique* items would be
something like this form.

```
-javaagent:(\S+)(?:.*?\s+-Dappdynamics(?:(\S+APP-NAME)|(\S+TIER-NAME)|(\S+{WAS_SERVER_NAME})|(\S+{HOSTNAME})))*
```

https://regex101.com/r/WXKWqW/1

***Note - Out-of-Order basically means, each literal item is always captured

in the same group, but it can be matched anywhere within the line.***

Obviously, the items should be unique.
In this example, 4 items per line are captured as well as the agent.
If an item is duplicated in the line, only the last one is captured.

Explained

```
 -javaagent:
 ( \S+ )                       # (1), agent

 (?:
      .*?                           # anything between 
      \s+ 
      -Dappdynamics
      (?:                           # Any of these
           ( \S+ APP-NAME )              # (2), app
        |  
           ( \S+ TIER-NAME )             # (3), tier
        |  
           ( \S+ {WAS_SERVER_NAME} )     # (4), server
        |  
           ( \S+ {HOSTNAME} )            # (5), host
      )
 )*
```

Comment: That's great!  Thanks. Your magic works great so far!  Continuing my further tests